# signature.verify doesn't return expected result

Tags: java, c++, c

I am trying to port some C code to JAVA code, some of security API need to be invoked both in C and JAVA, every parameter seems correct, but I always got false result. I am really frustrated, can anyone help me?

C code is:

```
    if (1 != RSA_verify(NID_sha1, md, sizeof(md), sig, sigLen, aikRsa)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Error, bad RSA signature in quote\n");
    exit (2);
}
```

aikRsa is read from PEM file via the API:

```
if ((aikRsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(key_file, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == NULL) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read RSA file %s\n", av[1]);
    exit (1);
}
```

the definition of RSA_verify:

```
int RSA_verify(int type, const unsigned char *m, unsigned int m_len,
unsigned char *sigbuf, unsigned int siglen, RSA *rsa);
```

the definition of PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY:

```
RSA *PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(FILE *fp, RSA **x,
                                    pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

equivalent JAVA code:

```
        Signature signature;
        signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        signature.initVerify(pubkey); 
        signature.update(md);
        if (!signature.verify(sig)) {
            log.error("signature is not correct\n");
        } else {
            log.info("signature is correct\n");
        }
```

I have compared the "sig" and "md" here with the value of "sig" and "md" in above C code, they are nearly the same except it's unsigned char to represent byte in C but in JAVA byte is always signed.

pubkey is got by follow function which is sample code i got from somewhere else.

```
public  PublicKey getPemPublicKey(String filename) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(filename);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    String temp = new String(keyBytes);
    String publicKeyPEM = temp.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");

    Base64 b64 = new Base64();
    byte [] decoded = b64.decode(publicKeyPEM);

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
          new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
    //KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    KeyFactory kf =  KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
    }
```

C code always return true, JAVA always return false, what's wrong here? appreciated for any of inputs.

Comment: sizeof(md) (in the first c part you quote) is returning the size of a char pointer, which I don't think is what you want, it wants the number of bytes in the message md is pointing to right?

Comment: @jacerate: thanks jacerate, C code works well, the issue is only existed with JAVA code, "md" in C code is defined as  `BYTE  md[20];`, so I don't thinks there is anything mistake.